# If two public getter function are returning same kind of output and both are uninitialised yet they why they charge different gas

Tags: solidity, gas, optimization

I am having a solidity code which is having two uint256 , while calling public getter function both charges different amount of gas why so ?

p.s both are uninitialised yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of how the code is executed in the ethereum virtual machine:

take a look at my example, here we have a smart contract with two public state variables and the compiler will generate two getter funcions

```
contract TestStorage{
  uint256 public b;
  uint256 public a;
}
```

and here we have a portion of the opcodes of my smart contract

[image]

for both cases the code to be executed is the same, as you can see it will load first the value 0xDBE671F (function selector of the first getter) and will compare it with the value sent, if the values are equal it will jump to the destination where the opcodes of that funcion are located, if the values are not equal it will continue executing the opcodes in the order you see in the image, until it find the opcode that load the second function selector: 0x4DF7E3D0 (second getter)
That means that when your try to read the second state variable it will cost more gas

so in summary the code is executed sequentially and it need to compare the function selector one by one until it find the correct

and that is why both functions charges different amount

take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxL_1AfV7N4&t=551s) to learn more

and you can read about how to debug your code in remix [here](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugger.html)

Answer (score 0):

During the contract execution, there's a "switch" statement that jumps to the correct function.

For example, in pseudo-code it may look like this:

```
mySelector = msg.data[0:4]

if (mySelector == 0x11111111) {
    // execute first function
} else if (mySelector == 0x22222222) {
    // execute second function
} else {...}
```

When executing the first function, it stops at the first `if`. Instead when executing the second function, it has to check both equations, meaning it goes through more opcodes, spending more gas.